# How can I reach an animation like the gmail Search

Tags: android, android-studio, android-animation

How can I reach an animation like this one in Gmail? A separated fragment just to the search screen?

[image: Animation]

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in this codelab by google:

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/material-motion-android/?return=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-week11-modern-ui%23codelab-%2Fcodelabs%2Fmaterial-motion-android%2F#5

you need to use the Shared Z-Axis transition as explained